# Python - Could not Exit from Tkinter using Menu.quit

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently learning python tkinter and have an issue regarding quiting tkinter window using explicit code.
Here's my code so far (I've simplified it to focus on the problem only)

```
from tkinter import *

def DoSomething():
    pass

root = Tk()
men = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = men)
submenu = Menu(men)
men.add_cascade(label = "File",menu = submenu)

submenu.add_command(label = "quit",command = Menu.quit)#Window does not close when user clicks "quit",
                                                       it just 
                                                       stays there non-responding

root.mainloop()
```

Any help regarding this is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: `Menu` is a *class* - it knows nothing about the actual objects comprising your application, so it can hardly tell them to close. `men.quit` might actually work, as you're now talking to an actual widget, but it's still bizarre: it's not the menu you want to close, it's the entire window.  Try `root.quit` as the command.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it.

Answer (score 5):

in python tkinter you're supposed to use the 'destroy' method to get rid of the tkinter window,i.e:

```
submenu.add_command(label="quit",command=root.destroy)
```

In your case.

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. Although, I want to know is there a difference between `quit` and `destroy`?

Comment: quit() stops the TCL interpreter. This is in most cases what you want, because your Tkinter-app will also stop. It can be a problem, if you e.g. call your app from idle. idle is itself a Tkinker-app, so if you call quit() in your app and the TCL interpreter gets terminated, idle will also terminate (or get confused ).

destroy() just terminates the mainloop and deletes all widgets. So it seems to be safer if you call your app from another Tkinter app, or if you have multiple mainloops."

taken from http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread66698.html